# How to set 5 bits to value 3 at offset 387 bit in byte data sequence?

Tags: dart, bit-manipulation

I need set some bits in ByteData at position counted in bits.
How I can do this?

Eg.

```dart
var byteData = new ByteData(1024);
var bitData = new BitData(byteData);
// Offset in bits: 387
// Number of bits: 5
// Value: 3
bitData.setBits(387, 5, 3);
```

Comment: Are you talking about bits or bytes? You can't set a binary bit to 3. It is either 1 or 0

Comment: @Phil_1984_:  Not a bytes but a bits. As in C language struct bit fields. Accordingly my example, as in packed C struct. Just re-read my question. It is very clear. How to manipulate with data with bits precision (offset in bits and values with width from 1-bit to 64-bit).

Comment: @Phil_1984_: `You can't set a binary bit to 3. It is either 1 or 0 ` Yes. But I not ask about this. I ask how set 5-bits (00000) to value 3 (00011). This is possible and correct.

Comment: Sorry.  I understand now.

Comment: Just calculate the byte offset and then set the right (shifted) value.

Comment: Would you accept a javascript based solution with explaining comments?

Comment: @Robert: What about endianness (byte order)? What if I want set a some bits in a two adjacent 32-bit data elements (inside the 64-bit field) and a start bit does not aligned to the byte boundary? The same as in C99 packed structs. Is there any easy answers such as you provide. Another problem: ~1 in Dart does not produce sized values as in C language. Eg. In Dart ~1 is -2, but in C it produce appropriate unsigned values, unsigned char uc1 = ~1 (254), unsigned ui1 = ~1 (4294967294). The same ~1 but diffirent bits. This is very hard in Dart manipulate with bits in fixed size integer range.

Comment: @Phil_1984_: `Would you accept a javascript based solution with explaining comments?` No. I work on my implementation and it will be ready soon... It is not easy (as you think) when you need get/set bit frames in adjacent sequence elements. Eg. `bitData.set64(1, 64, 0xffffffffffffffff)`. Set value 0xffffffffffffffff in 64-bit frame in two adjacent 64-bit elements in data sequence when start offset is at 1-bit (second after 0-bit). Also bit frames can be signed. Bit frame with 1-bit size can hold only two values (0 and -1). Your suggestion take this into account?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is quite complicated.  I dont know dart, but these are the general steps you need to take.  I will label each variable as a letter and also use a more complicated example to show you what happens when the bits overflow.

```
1. Construct the BitData object with a ByteData object (A)

2. Call setBits(offset (B), bits (C), value (D));

I will use example values of: 

A: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
B: 7 
C: 10
D: 00000000 11111111

3. Rather than using an integer with a fixed length of bits, you could
use another ByteData object (D) containing your bits you want to write.  
Also create a mask (E) containing the significant bits.

e.g. 
A: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
D: 00000000 11111111
E: 00000011 11111111 (2^C - 1)

4. As an extra bonus step, we can make sure the insignificant 
bits are really zero by ANDing with the bitmask.

D = D & E

D 00000000 11111111
E 00000011 11111111

5. Make sure D and E contain at least one full zero byte since we want
to shift them.

D 00000000 00000000 11111111
E 00000000 00000011 11111111

6. Work out these two integer values:

F = The extra bit offset for the start byte: B mod 8 (e.g. 7)
G = The insignificant bits: size(D) - C (e.g. 14)

7. H = G-F which should not be negative here. (e.g. 14-7 = 7)

8. Shift both D and E left by H bits.

D 00000000 01111111 10000000
E 00000001 11111111 10000000

9. Work out first byte number (J) floor(B / 8) e.g. 0

10. Read the value of A at this index out and let this be K

K = 11111111 11111111 11111111

11. AND the current (K) with NOT E to set zeros for the new bits.  
Then you can OR the new bits over the top.

L = (K & !E) | D

K & !E = 11111110 00000000 01111111
L = 11111110 01111111 11111111

12. Write L to the same place you read it from.
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no `BitData` class, so you'll have to do some of the bit-pushing yourself.

Find the corresponding byte offset, read in some bytes, mask out the existing bits and set the new ones at the correct bit offset, then write it back.
The real complexity comes when you need to store more bits than you can read/write in a single operation.

For endianness, if you are treating the memory as a sequence of bits with arbitrary width, I'd go for little-endian. Endianness only really makes sense for full-sized (2^n-bit, n > 3) integers. A 5 bit integer as the one you are storing can't have any endianness, and a 37 bit integer also won't have any natural way of expressing an endianness.

You can try something like this code (which can definitely be optimized more):

```dart
import "dart:typed_data";
void setBitData(ByteBuffer buffer, int offset, int length, int value) {
  assert(value < (1 << length));
  assert(offset + length < buffer.lengthInBytes * 8);
  int byteOffset = offset >> 3;
  int bitOffset = offset & 7;
  if (length + bitOffset <= 32) {
    ByteData data = new ByteData.view(buffer);
    // Can update it one read/modify/write operation.
    int mask = ((1 << length) - 1) << bitOffset;
    int bits = data.getUint32(byteOffset, Endianness.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    bits = (bits & ~mask) | (value << bitOffset);
    data.setUint32(byteOffset, bits, Endianness.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    return;
  }
  // Split the value into chunks of no more than 32 bits, aligned.
  do {
    int bits = (length > 32 ? 32 : length) - bitOffset;
    setBitData(buffer, offset, bits, value & ((1 << bits) - 1));
    offset += bits;
    length -= bits;
    value >>= bits;
    bitOffset = 0;
  } while (length > 0);
}
```

Example use:

```dart
main() {
  var b = new Uint8List(32);
  setBitData(b.buffer, 3, 8, 255);
  print(b.map((v)=>v.toRadixString(16)));
  setBitData(b.buffer, 13, 6*4, 0xffffff);
  print(b.map((v)=>v.toRadixString(16)));
  setBitData(b.buffer, 47, 21*4, 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa);
  print(b.map((v)=>v.toRadixString(16)));
}
```